# CanActivate Guard doesn't seem to subscribe to observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an angular application which has a number of steps to complete. Each step can only be done once and must have all previous steps complete. To achieve this I have added route guards to each route. The application makes a http request on start to check the status. However the route guard `canActivate` method doesn't seem to be subscribing to changes.

In the below example `statusService` updates the status which should trigger an update in the guards.

#### statusService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StatusService {

  private stepOneComplete: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  private stepTwoComplete: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public getStepOneComplete(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.stepOneComplete;
  };

  public updateStepOneComplete(newValue: boolean): void {
    this.stepOneComplete.next(newValue);
  };

  public initialize(): void {
    this.http.get(`${apiUrl}status`)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.stepOneComplete(data.stepOne);
      });
  };
};
```

#### stepOneGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class StepOneGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private service: StatusService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.service.getStepOneComplete().pipe(
      tap(complete => {
        if(complete){
          this.router.navigate(['/step-two']);
        }
      }),
      map(complete => {
        return !complete;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

What I expect to happen is that after the initialize method runs and updates `stepOneComplete` then the router should navigate to step two. However no navigation occurs. If I put a `console.log` in the `tap` method of the guard it fires on initial load but not when `stepOneComplete.next` is called.

Comment: I think you missunderstood the behavior of the app guard at this point, see https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate. You have to navigate yourself to step-two. The app guard is just able to interrupt this navigation via canActivate.

Comment: why you do     map(complete => {
        return !complete;
      })

Comment: maybe you want to use a lib including such a wizard handling, see https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/steps

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh The problem I'm trying to solve is that my route guards depends on an observable. If a user completes step one I navigate them to step 2, however they may be on another route in the application not related to these steps so I can't just navigate to step 2 on load if the API tells me step 1 is complete in the initialize response.

Comment: @FanCheung because user cannot navigate to step 1 if it is already complete.

Comment: So you only want to navigate on page load if step 1 is completed? Also in this case you have to explicit navigate the router from within the initialize subscribe, because the app guard wont automaticaly. The app guard acts like an listener on naviagate protecting the navigation target by the canActivate function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here:

```
public getStepOneComplete(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.stepOneComplete.asObservable();
}
```

This is what I have in my own production code, works just fine.

Comment: BehaviorSubject is a subclass of Observable, see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html so this is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should not see a guard as a singleton that controls navigation. Its only purpose is to control whether the user can access a page or not.

I suggest you to have a state service that holds the state of your "wizard", and then you would simply check it in every guard. You shouldn't even need Subjects at all.

Comment: I agree, something like this would work. But you can reuse one guard for all your routes.

Comment: Indeed OP could use `canActivate` parameters to build one generic guard